# Incorrect battery charge percentages

Tags: catalina, battery

I bought a new battery for my Macbook. Besides not giving an accurate indication of the battery (*due to a calibration issue I guess*), it gives a different value to the Mac and the coconutBattery. What could be the reason?

[image: coconutBattery screenshot]

Comment: *"due to a calibration issue"* - how did you calibrate it?

Comment: @Tetsujin TBH I had not known this term till today, what I have been doing is to drain it off completely and then charging again, it initially was showing 100% right after 100% but I kept charging which let it reach to 99%

Comment: See this method - https://www.ifixit.com/Wiki/Battery_Calibration

Comment: @Tetsujin I thought that this was only necessary some years ago; Apple no longer recommend recalibration. I certainly wouldn't run it down once a month.

Comment: @Volatil3 Apart from the difference between the OS and CoconutBattery, what do you mean by it does not give an "accurate indication"...? As long as you get, say,  5 hours or more for medium workload, and the battery stays good for another 3 years: then there's not really much more you can do.

Answer (score 6):

Coconut Battery and Apple use different methods to calculate the percentage.

The Coconut Battery FAQ says:

> iOS uses a defensive calculated battery capacity value to define 100%
> (and the percentage calculation). coconutBattery reads out the raw
> battery data and can give you more precise information.  (for example
> you will see that the device actually is still charging when iOS tells
> you that it is fully charged).

(It says iOS, but the principle is the same.)

A quick Google shows lots of people asking this question.

Any figure is going to be a rough guide rather than a measurement that you can use in any accurate determination of anything.